# I try to make filter checkbox with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

[image]

Can someone help my with business logic when I try to find products in my bd list with properties from `ProductFilterVM` or give my advice where I can find solution.

```cs
public class ProductFilterVM
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
// other properties relating to a product that you may want to display the view - e.g. Description
    public IEnumerable<FilterCategoryVM>? FilterCategories { get; set; }
}

public class FilterCategoryVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<FilterSelectionVM>? Selections { get; set; }
}
public class FilterSelectionVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You wanna create a view to select FilterSelectionVM in list?

Comment: @XinranShen something like this. I added photo

Comment: please provide some code about your view.

Comment: @XinranShen I need to add filtration, pagination and sorting. I 'm in process. My view it's just a list of products (List<ProductVM>).